# How to make Flex Air FileSystemTree to show in Package view

Tags: apache-flex, air, filesystems, package

I am using Flex FileSystemTree.

Inside my root folder I got one folder with 3 files in it.

In order to brows to my files using FileSystemTree, I need to open my root folder, to open my inner folder and only then I get the files.

I wish that if the the folder got no files it will present as package, just like in eclipse. so I only need to open one folder(root.innerfolder)

I hope my question is clear, please tell me if not.

Comment: Can't do it out of the box: you'll have to write (or find) a custom component.

Comment: Sorry, I would've told you if I did.